# Azure: Using a sasToken to create a CloudTableClient

Tags: azure

I can't seem to create a `CloudTableClient` using a shared-access-key that doesn't result in 403: Forbidden exceptions.

I've tried every possible configuration of consturctor/builder parameters that I can think of and none of them seem to work:

`TableClient = new CloudTableClient(new Uri(sasKey), new StorageCredentials(sasKey)); // 403`

`TableClient = new CloudStorageAccount(
                new StorageCredentials(sasKey), 
                useHttps: true,
                accountName: "stackoverflow",
                endpointSuffix: "core.windows.net"
            ).CreateCloudTableClient(); // 403`

etc...

What is the correct way to use sas tokens with cloud tables in azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: The correct method for me was to create the CloudTable itself using the token: `UnitTable = new CloudTable(new Uri(sasKey));`.